# Add mouseover to all buttons on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to add a mouseover/mouseout css class change to ALL buttons on a page through, for example, some JavaScript in the page header, without having to give each individual button its own onmouseover and onmouseout events? It seems very inefficient that I would have to add this to every single button on all of my pages:

```
onmouseover="javascript:this.className='ui-state-hover';" onmouseout="javascript:this.className='ui-state-default';"
```

There must be an easier way to do this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your elements a class and then you go about something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    // search for element with class myclass
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
      if (elms[i].getAttribute('class') === 'myclass'){

        elms[i].onmouseover = function(){
          this.className='ui-state-hover'
        }

        elms[i].onmouseout = function(){
          this.className='ui-state-default'
        }

      }
    }
}
```

Just apply the class `myclass` to your input boxes.

**With jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $('.myclass').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('ui-state-hover');
  }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('ui-state-default');
  });
});
```

Comment: The jQuery bit works perfectly, thanks! I really love jQuery :D Probably should have mentioned that I'm using it.

Comment: @jorrit: Yes, definitely mention when you're using jQuery, so people know it's okay to give you just jQuery-specific answers. You'll get more answers, faster.

Comment: It might still be better to use `live()` or `delegate()` to avoid binding a bunch of event handlers. @jorrit: Yes, mention it before other people break their fingers when writing plain JavaScript ;) And you should still consider to use CSS instead.

Answer (score 3):

[If you don't need to support IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16), make use of CSS `:hover`:

```
button, 
input[type=button], 
input[type=reset], 
input[type=submit] {
    // all properties of `ui-state-default` here
}

button:hover,
input[type=button]:hover, 
input[type=reset]:hover, 
input[type=submit]:hover {
    // all properties of `ui-state-hover` here
}
```

---

Otherwise, you can use *event delegation* through [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

<del>*(for W3C compatible browser)*</del>

```
function getHandler(cls) {
    var types = {'submit': true, 'reset': true, 'button': true};
    return function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        if(target.nodeName === "BUTTON"
           || (target.nodeName === "INPUT" && target.type in types)) {
            event.target.className = cls;
        }
    }
}

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onmouseover', getHandler('ui-state-hover'));
    window.attachEvent('onmouseout', getHandler('ui-state-default'));
}
else {
    window.addEventListener('mouseover', getHandler('ui-state-hover'), false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseout', getHandler('ui-state-default'), false);
}
```

*Edit: Cross-browser compatible and more sophisticated*

For more information, have a look at [*Advanced event registration models - qurirksmode.org*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) and [*Event properties - quirksmode.org*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: I think you mean `tagName` (rather than `nodeName`). And you might want to support `input[type=button]` as well as `button`. And you can support IE easily enough, via `attachEvent`.

Comment: @TJCrowder: `nodeName` should work as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeName. Yes, the test might gave to be adjusted (but the OP is not specifying which "buttons") and I was just too lazy to make it cross browser compatible ;)

Comment: Fair enough, I'd forgotten that `nodeName` == `tagName` when the node is an Element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to make it work something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:button").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-hover');
    });

    $("input:button").mouseout(function() {
         $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover').addClass('ui-state-default');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(
  $('button').mouseover(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-hover');
  });

  $('button').mouseout(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover').addClass('ui-state-default');
  });

);
```